# How to enable pagination for datatable ajax

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, datatable

I have datatable that collects data from mysql database using express js, In view tried to show 10 entries but it show all the entries instead of 10. How can i fixed it?

here is my datatable script

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: "/penulis/daftar-penulis/data",
                    type: "GET",
                },
                paging: true,
                // data: data,
                columns: [
                    { data: "tbl_nomor", title: "Nomor" },
                    { data: "tbl_kode", title: "Kode Pengguna" },
                    { data: "tbl_nama", title: "Nama" },
                    { data: "tbl_status", title: "Status" },
                ],
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        targets: 0,
                        width: "10%",
                    },
                    {
                        width: "15%",
                        targets: 3,
                    },
                    {
                        width: "10%",
                        targets: 4,
                        data: null,
                        defaultContent: "<button>Click!</button>",
                    },
                ],
            });

            $("#example tbody").on("click", "button", function () {
                var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();

                console.log(data.tbl_kode);
                alert(data.tbl_nama);
            });
```

Here is express js code

```
 if (typeof req.query.order == "undefined") {
        var column_name = "nomor";
        var column_sort_order = "desc";
    } else {
        var column_index = req.query.order[0]["column"];
        var column_name = req.query.columns[column_index]["data"];
        var column_sort_order = req.query.order[0]["dir"];
    }
    var search_value = req.query.search["value"];

    var search = `AND (nomor LIKE '%${search_value}%'
        OR nama_depan LIKE '%${search_value}%'
        OR nama_belakang LIKE '%${search_value}%'
        OR kode_pengguna LIKE '%${search_value}%'
        OR status LIKE '%${search_value}%'
    )`;

    con.query("SELECT COUNT(nomor) AS Total FROM datatable", (err, data) => {
        var recordsTotal = data[0].Total;
        console.log("Jumlah record : " + recordsTotal);

        con.query(
            `SELECT COUNT(nomor) AS Total FROM datatable WHERE 1 ${search}`,
            (err, data) => {
                var recordsFiltered = data[0].Total;
                console.log(
                    "Jumlah record yang terfilter : " + recordsFiltered
                );

                var sql = `SELECT * FROM datatable WHERE 1 ${search} ORDER BY nomor ${column_sort_order}`;
                var resultData = [];
                con.query(sql, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    data.forEach((item) => {
                        resultData.push({
                            tbl_nomor: item.nomor,
                            tbl_kode: item.kode_pengguna,
                            tbl_nama:
                                item.nama_depan + " " + item.nama_belakang,
                            tbl_status: item.status,
                            tbl_aksi: "Aksi",
                        });
                    });
                    var output = {
                        draw: req.query.draw,
                        recordsTotal: recordsTotal,
                        recordsFiltered: recordsFiltered,
                        data: resultData,
                    };
                    res.json(output);
                });
            }
        );
    });
```

Here is the view :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHC0Q.png)

how can i show 10 entries instead of all entries from database

Comment: try "pageLength": 10